# Make pop up research for CSS file on load

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm writing a site using Java Servlets and JSP pages. I need to have a pop up open from one of the pages, and it can reload itself if the user fails to follow the instructions before clicking a submit button. The problem is as follows:

1. the CSS files are in `Home/JSP files`
2. when the current page loads, it searches for the CSS file in `JSP/style.CSS` because it loads via the servlet and it thinks it works in `Home`.
3. When the link to the pop up is clicked on, it still believes itself to be in `Home/JSP files`, so in order for it to find the CSS file I need to point it to just `style.CSS`. But once the user screws up and the pop up has to reload, this goes via the servlet, which believes itself to be in `Home`, so it searches for `Home/style.CSS`, doesn't find it, and renders the pop up without the style.

One obvious solution is to keep the CSS files in `Home`, but I dislike file arrangements where everything is not neatly compartmentized in their own folders, so I was wondering if there's a way to resolve this without moving files.

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the URL of your CSS files start the URL with a / to indicate that it is relative to the root of your site. Then it does not matter what context you refer to the CSS file in, it will always resolve it from the root.

e.g.

```
  /Home/JSP/myfile.css
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I agree that it makes sense to use a full path, but it still renders it without styling on the first load.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Domain-relative paths must work regardless of the opened resource. Ensure that you've a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Home/JSP/style.CSS">` in every JSP.